# Why is the passive form verb 「おられる」used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, manga

Here is the sentence.

白木葉子さんは非行少年問題にご理解がふかく学生劇団を組織して日曜日ごとにあちこちの少年院を慰問してまわって**おられる**のだ

In my understanding, the objective for the verb is 「あちこちの少年院」.

Is the verb used in passive form because of showing politness or respect to 「白木葉子さん」?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a question & answer directly related in this page. http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1432636889, so citing it here.

---

It is a form to show respect called 敬語. To make the form, append the auxiliary verb られる.

- して いる: Normal form.
- して お られる: Form for respect.

There are two verbs here. して and いる。When there are two verbs, the last one is affected.

Note that the conjugation is irregular in this case. If the rule is applied simply, it will be:

- して いる: Normal
- して い られる: Form for respect.

However, いられる for respect is replaced with おられる.

---

I believe it is because いられる means "allowed to" such as you are allowed to be there. To avoid confusion, it is replaced with おられる。Perhaps someone can give better explanation on this irregularity.